# Como relacionar correctamente entidades en spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Tengo 4 tablas

Area: es un catalogo donde existen todos los departamentos de una organizacion (padre)

subAreas: Es una catalogo donde existe todas las subAreas que pertenecen alcatalogo de Areas es decir  (hija)

personal: Catalogo dodne existen todos los empleados de la organización

personal_Area: Es una tabla donde estan todas las relacionas de las anteriores tablas

La logica de negocio es sencilla un empleado puede pertenecer a uno a varias areas y solo a una subarea por cada area a la que pertenece

**Aqui mis relaciones**

[image: Aquí mis relaciones]

Mis entidades son las sig.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personal", catalog = "almacen", schema = "")
public class Personal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "curp")
    private String curp;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 200)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personal")
    private Set<PersonalArea> registrations = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Personal Area

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "personal_area", catalog = "almacen", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
public class PersonalArea {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "personal_id")

    private Personal personal;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "area_id")
    private Area area;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subarea_id")
    private subArea subArea;
    
    private Date fechaCreacion;

}
```

Area

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "area", catalog = "almacen", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
public class Area {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    private String nombreArea;
    @JsonIgnore

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "area")
    private Set<PersonalArea> registrations = new HashSet<>();


}
```

SubArea

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_area", catalog = "almacen", schema = "")
public class subArea {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    private Long idArea;
    private String nombre;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personal")
    private Set<PersonalArea> registrations = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Con lo anterior obtengo el sig. json

```
{
    "items": [{
            "id": 1,
            "personal": {
                "id": 1,
                "curp": "AEMM680119HHGRRR03",
                "nombre": "MARIO RUBIZEL",
                "primerApellido": "ARTEAGA",
                "segundoApellido": "MORALES",
                "telefono": "7711263949",
                "fechaCreacion": null,
                "fechaModificacion": null
            },
            "area": {
                "id": 2,
                "nombreArea": "PERSONAL ADMINISTRATIVO"
            },
            "subArea": {
                "id": 1,
                "idArea": 2,
                "nombre": "CONTROL ESCOLAR"
            },
            "fechaCreacion": "2021-06-24T16:26:49.000+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "personal": {
                "id": 1,
                "curp": "AEMM680119HHGRRR03",
                "nombre": "MARIO RUBIZEL",
                "primerApellido": "ARTEAGA",
                "segundoApellido": "MORALES",
                "telefono": "7711263949",
                "fechaCreacion": null,
                "fechaModificacion": null
            },
            "area": {
                "id": 5,
                "nombreArea": "PERSONAL EXTERNO"
            },
            "subArea": {
                "id": 2,
                "idArea": 5,
                "nombre": "FOTOCOPIADO"
            },
            "fechaCreacion": "2021-06-24T16:26:49.000+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Como pueden observar el json sale dos veces la misma persona, lo que yo necesito es algo como esto:

```
{
        "items": [{
                "id": 1,
                "personal": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "curp": "AEMM680119HHGRRR03",
                    "nombre": "MARIO RUBIZEL",
                    "primerApellido": "ARTEAGA",
                    "segundoApellido": "MORALES",
                    "telefono": "7711263949",
                    "fechaCreacion": null,
                    "fechaModificacion": null
                },
                "area": [{
                        "id": 1,
                        "nombreArea": "DIRECTOR",
                        "subArea": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "idArea": 2,
                            "nombre": "CONTROL ESCOLAR"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "nombreArea": "PERSONAL EXTERNO",
                        "subArea": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "idArea": 5,
                            "nombre": "FOTOCOPIADO"
                        }
                    }

                ],
                "fechaCreacion": "2021-06-24T16:26:49.000+00:00"
            }

        ]
    }
```

Hay la manera de hacer lo que yo necesito?... debo de cambiar algo en mi diseño de DB para lograrlo?

Comment: Hola Héctor, podrías compartir como es que estás leyendo la información de la base de datos? Imagino ocupas JPA pero sería bueno ver como lo estás haciendo.

Comment: Asi es estoy ocupando JPA... Tendrías idea de como hacer eso?

Comment: SI pudieras compartir como estás haciendo el fetch podría tener una mejor idea.

Comment: @ferroblesh podrías ayudarme con esta pregunta porfavor?  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489008/como-usar-correctamente-los-joins-in-specifications

Comment: Eso es problema tuyo, en la bd el id 1 y el id 2 tiene el mismo personal por eso sale repe

Comment: Cada area tiene un perosnal de area , una sub area . en tu caso el area 1 y el 2 tiene el mismo personal ese es el proble,ma