# Como usar correctamente los joins in Specifications

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Tengo las sig 2 tablas...
LoteResguardo se puede decir que es la entidad padre que tiene hijos (muchos resguardos)..

```
public class LoteResguardo implements Serializable  {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@NotNull
private Long id;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idLote",  fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Resguardos> resguardos;

}
```

la sig clase es Resguardos (hija)

```
@Table(name = "resguardos")
 public class Resguardos implements Serializable    {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@NotNull
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idActivo", referencedColumnName="id")
private Activos activo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idLote", referencedColumnName="id")
private LoteResguardo idLote;

@Column(name = "status")
private Boolean status;

@Column(name = "fechaResguardo", nullable = false)
private Date fechaResguardo;

@Column(name = "fechaDevolucion", nullable = true)
private Date fechaDevolucion;


}
```

Tengo la siguiente specification

```
    public static < Y > Specification < LoteResguardo > getLotesFilterSpec(JSONArray filters) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) - > {

            ArrayList < Predicate > pred = new ArrayList < Predicate > ();
            Iterator < Object > it = filters.iterator();

            // Filtrar
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) it.next();



                if (Stream.of("idResguardo").anyMatch(obj.getString("property")::equalsIgnoreCase)) {

                    query.distinct(true);


                    Join < LoteResguardo, Resguardos > item = root.join("resguardos", JoinType.LEFT);



                    pred.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("resguardos").get(("id")), 1));


                }



                return criteriaBuilder.and(pred.toArray(new Predicate[pred.size()]));
            }
        }
```

Deseo retornar solo el resguardo con el id: 1 (un record), pero no es posible si el loteResguardo tiene muchos resguardos, es decir me retorna todos que tiene asociado el idLote en la tabla resguardos...

por ejemplo tengo estos records de la tabla resguardos

[image: ejemplo de records]

quisiera retornar con la spec solo un record con el id, pero como mencione me devuelve todos lo que están asociados al idLote en este caso los 4

Podrían decirme que me esta faltando?
Gracias de ya! :)